# IIS app connection error to another machine SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

We are facing issue on connecting database on another machine on LAN. the code connection works fine while we run in from vs project and it make effect on other pc database but throw error when we host it on iis on local machine. we try many settings but no success until now.

SQL code sample

```
 update OPENDATASOURCE('SQLN211',  
                       'Data Source=ABC;User ID=sa;Password=ABC;Integrated Security=SSPI').ServerName.dbo.EmpAtt
```

Error

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

Comment: Your need to create a trust between your webserver and database server machines in Active Directory. Currently your Application Pool user authenticating using Integrated Security is rejected because your database machine does not trust users authenticating on your webserver machine.

Comment: If you want to use User ID and Password then set Integrated Security=False;

Comment: I would suggest removing your sa password from your connection string!! Check you have your site and its app pool configured to run under the correct account.

Comment: If you want to use a user ID and password, you need to set Server Authentication to SQL Server and windows Authentication mode. In addition, you need to allow the account to log in to SQL Server.